# O que podemos fazer para incentivar a participação no Meta?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Nós estamos tendo discussões bem produtivas aqui no meta. O problema é que apenas "meia dúzia de gatos pingados" estão aparecendo por aqui para participar e decidindo assuntos importantes.

Claro que seria simples dizer que é azar o deles, mas uma comunidade saudável precisa de uma grande participação para ter legitimidade de tomar um rumo baseado no que muitos querem e não apenas no que nós poucos queremos.

Sei que não é pergunta fácil de responder mas temos que tomar essa responsabilidade de trazer mais membros para participar.

Que ações podem ser feitas para trazer pessoas novas para participar?

Comment: Não acho que deva incentivar. No meta tudo funciona a base de opinião, só vem para cá quem aceita _levar porrada_. IMHO

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Penso que a melhor maneira de incentivar os utilizadores a virem ao site META é efetivamente deixar um comentário sempre que alguma situação carece uma discussão na META sobre determinado assunto.

Desta forma, não só promovemos o uso do site META como damos a conhecer que existe um local onde podemos discutir assuntos para melhorar o site principal expressando a nossa opinião sem encher as perguntas e respostas com comentários de certa forma inúteis ao tópico.

Comment: Concordo com o Zuul, e além disso que ele citou estou propagando com a galera da [empresa](http://www.marttech.com.br), aos poucos estão todos virando participantes da comunidade.

Answer (score 5):

Um post oficial do Gabe, com direito a chamada no boletim da comunidade, viria a calhar.

Answer (score 0):

Notificações na caixa de entrada e/ou pelo e-mail dos usuários do beta privado.

Comment: Isso está fora da política do site. O contato direto com os membros só ocorrem se a notificação for fundamental para ele, ou algo muito grave tenha acontecido.

Comment: Nem como forma de convite (um apenas e não spam)?, algo semelhante ao convite do beta privado.