# Aqui É UM Stack Overflow. Qual?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade

> **Nota histórica:** isto foi postado ainda antes do site passar para o beta público, mas ainda assim a discussão continua válida.

[O post inaugural do nosso meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com?cb=1), pendurado no boletim da comunidade aí à direita, é bem-intencionado, mas comete um [equívoco que o Stack Overflow já cometeu antes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted): tentar descrever o site por aquilo que ele *não* é. Certo, o Stack Overflow tem *suas* regras (mesmo que por vezes mudem ou não sejam tão claras), e não precisamos segui-las todas ao pé da letra. Mas precisamos decidir quais vamos seguir, e criar novas quando necessário.

O *[Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com)*, dá duas grandes diretrizes, importantes porém vagas:

> Isso não quer dizer que vale-tudo

e

> Deixe para amanhã uma regra que você não precisa hoje

Uma parte desse "amanhã" já chegou e precisamos de algumas regras. Não todas (impossível criar um conjunto estável de regras nesse momento), mas pelo menos algumas que sejam claras.

Os exemplos do que estaria claramente fora segundo o post inaugural – [diversão social boba](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) não vale, nem ser "puramente subjetivo" – são amplos demais. E nesta altura, isto já parece insuficiente:

> Via de regra, por enquanto é melhor permitir qualquer pergunta que satisfaça as seguintes condições:
>
> - **Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?**
> - **Ela aumenta ou diminui o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?**

*Não quer dizer que vale-tudo*, não é mesmo?

#### Mas então o que vale? E como decidir isso?

A Stack Exchange possui um conjunto de diretrizes que valem para todos os sites da rede – cada um com sua própria "receita" de como elas são combinadas e dosadas. Aqui, misteriosamente, **nenhuma** foi oficialmente citada até agora (exceto pela vaga menção ao "puramente subjetivo"). Eu não gostaria que a Stack Exchange chegasse aqui autoritariamente impondo isto ou aquilo (e nem parece ser o que eles querem), mas seria importante ter dado algumas balizas em relação a assuntos que cedo ou tarde iriam aparecer. Seria importante ter participado mais das discussões no meta, com votos, opiniões, comentários, e postagem de perguntas que discutissem o que estava acontecendo no site.

Alguns membros da comunidade (entre os quais me incluo) procuram discutir o site intensamente no nosso meta, recolhendo boas opiniões sobre diversos assuntos. Abrimos discussões conforme fomos encontrando perguntas e respostas de determinados tipos potencialmente problemáticos, e debatemos as opções para lidarmos com elas. Foram traduzidos dois [artigos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) [seminais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark) do [Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/) – antes que sequer fossem mencionados oficialmente pela Stack Exchange – para que servissem como subsídios as discussões. Alguns postaram no site perguntas moldadas para testar a reação da comunidade sobre um assunto, em seguida debatido no meta.

Talvez o mais importante seja que entendemos que aqui não é o Stack Overflow, e estamos dispostos a aceitar decisões da comunidade mesmo que venham a ser contrárias às nossas opiniões pessoais. Mesmo assim, às vezes somos tidos como "interventores" por certos usuários – especialmente quando o azarado tem uma pergunta "sorteada" como mote de uma de nossas discussões. Tudo bem, é por uma causa nobre. *Tornar a internet um lugar melhor*, certo? Mas quando nos questionam, há um incômodo: somos uma meia dúzia de usuários, um número muito baixo para que possamos dizer que nossas conclusões sejam "o consenso da comunidade". Para chegar a isso precisamos de mais opiniões no meta, e de mais participação da Stack Exchange.

Apesar do volume de discussões que postamos no meta, nós mesmos (ou pelo menos eu) temos dado pouco nossas opiniões em forma de votos quando esses votos carregam um valor negativo: votos contra, votos para fechar, votos para excluir. Percebi que isso está errado. Mais usuários precisam expressar o que pensam de cada pergunta, em forma de votos de todo tipo, comentários e discussões no meta. Só assim conseguiremos sentir o que "a comunidade" aprova ou reprova. Sem isso, teremos uma bagunça completa. Se mais gente fizer isso, é bem possível que o clima do site esquente um pouco, mas acredito que no final teremos um site melhor.

Comment: Eu precisava ler isto neste momento (que a participação aqui no meta é bem-vinda, independente da opinião expressada). Obrigado.

Comment: Nem eu me lembrava que já tinha tocado nesse assunto de o site parecer hostil, de certos usuários serem vistos como "interventores". Você me lembrou desta discussão na hora certa.

Answer (score 13):

Vou começar comentando a resposta do Zuul.

Eu sou o autor da pergunta [O que podemos fazer para incentivar a participação no Meta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313/o-que-podemos-fazer-para-incentivar-a-participacao-no-meta) e nem preciso dizer como acho isso importante.
Mas tem uma coisa que também temos que tomar cuidado. É um pouco polêmico porque pode parecer que não quero ouvir todos os usuários. Claro que temos que ouvir todos. Mas é preciso cuidado com participações "hit and run" ou quase isso. Alguns usuários só participam em algo do seu interesse específico.

É preciso analisar com cautela o que usuários que só aparecem para um ponto ou outro, onde aquilo desperta a atenção dele por algum motivo, mas ele não quer participar de todos os debates. Quem participa de tudo provavelmente está pensando na comunidade acima dos seus interesses. Quem aparece aqui ou ali, que nem mesmo lê tudo o que tem e vota no que concorda ou discorda (em geral respostas) ou no que é relevante discutir (em geral perguntas) pode estar pensando estritamente na comunidade, mas como vamos saber com uma participação tão pequena?

"Ah, mas eu não tenho tempo para participar mais"

Ok. O mundo não é perfeito, a vida não é justa, mas a única forma de alguém conseguir, no mínimo, influenciar nos rumos de alguma comunidade de qualquer tipo é participando. Pode parecer cruel, mas a mais simples verdade é que o usuário que não tem tempo para participar, terá que aceitar o que for decidido pelos que têm tempo. Não há outra forma de fazer isso.

Pode não ser o ideal, mas na prática, bem menos que 2% vão decidir o que, bem mais que 98% terão que seguir. Até porque grande parte dos assuntos já estão definidos na plataforma e nós não podemos fazer do jeito que bem entendemos.

Eu adoraria que isso não fosse verdade e vou me esforçar para que seja menos verdade, mas não tem muito o que fazer.

O resto do post dele, concordo com tudo.

## Tentando responder a pergunta (?)

A discussão aqui é relevante e votei nela. Mas não gosto muito do caminho trilhado.

A parte fácil: ok, as regras precisam ser criadas e serão criadas aos poucos, não dá para definir tudo agora. Toda vez que surge uma pergunta ou outro problema que precisamos saber como agir, **vamos postar uma discussão aqui no meta**.

As perguntas citadas no post inaugural são bem ruins para definir qualquer coisa:

- **Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?**

  Bem vaga, subjetiva e eu não sei como responder precisamente. Cada um terá sua própria definição. É um slogan engraçadinho mas na prática não pode ser usada como parâmetro definitivo para decidir se a pergunta é boa.
- **Ela aumenta ou diminui o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?**

  Como eu vou saber? Mesmo que eu tente e diga "se mantiver essa aqui aberta, uma pessoa a mais irá se beneficiar do site". Isso tem pelo menos dois problemas:

  1. Cartoon favorito pode beneficiar várias pessoas. Pergunte para elas se não pode. Sempre foi extremamente votada. Posso dar vários argumentos porque o cartoon pode beneficiar um programador. De fato me beneficiou de algumas formas. Nem por isso acho uma boa pergunta.
  2. Vamos supor que, por exemplo o mgibsonbr e utluiz (os dois usuários de maior reputação no momento, poderia ser outras pessoas, até mesmo que nem chegaram no site ainda), não gostem de lidar com certos tipos de pergunta e que chegue num ponto que eles fiquem desconfortáveis em administrar isso. Um resolve sair atirando pra todo lado do absurdo que virou o site e outro sai silenciosamente (como já sei que aconteceu com pelo menos um usuário, fora os casos de quem eu sei que não querem vir porque potencialmente o SOpt pode ter cara de fórum, que é o que brasileiro gosta). E vamos supor que essas perguntas que eles não gostam são as que trouxeram dezenas de usuários para cá, talvez só para fazer uma pergunta e mais nada. Temos usuários que ajudam bastante a comunidade e temos outros que pouco fazem. Todos são importantes mas vale à pena fazer essa troca dos usuários que mais contribuem por um punhado de usuário que contribuem pouco? Devemos escolher aceitar as perguntas que alguns usuários acham ruins para aumentar o número de usuários do site?

Sinceramente gostei daquele texto inaugural por dar bastante liberdade e não quererem que o SOpt seja igual ao SO, dizendo que podemos ter outras coisas. Mas não gostei de sugerirem colocar quase todo o mercado de TI aqui e aceitar quase qualquer pergunta que não seja muito ruim.

Parece que está havendo, de forma inconsistente, uma onda para realmente aceitarmos perguntas mais variadas.

Para responder isso, achei uma resposta muito boa [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124706/140010).

**O que "fazer a internet melhor" significa:**

- Fazer uma informação que é difícil de achar, fácil de achar;
- Destacar (de várias formas) a informação mais correta;

  - Manter informação que depende do tempo válida (ou impedir que algo desatualizado seja considerado relevante);
- Fazer **informações complicadas** mais acessíveis e fáceis de entender;
- Reduzir o ruído de conversas, opiniões, discursos, e outras distrações.

**"Fazer a internet melhor" NÃO significa que:**

- Toda pergunta deve ser preservada, nem que todo conteúdo fora do escopo deve ser apagado do site. O conteúdo deve ser julgado pelo seu próprio mérito;
- Devemos aceitar um concurso de popularidade. O que as pessoas *gostam* e o que as *beneficiam de forma prática* são coisas bem diferentes;
- Ela deve ser melhor para *todo mundo*. O possível efeito positivo para um deve ser contraposto com o *potencial* efeito negativo em outros;
- Deva ser justificativa para qualquer ação da comunidade, apesar de fazermos isso para simplificar a explicação. Várias regras e critérios foram criados ao longo de anos para determinar como agir. Essas ações precisam ser justificadas por motivos mais objetivos e claros;
- É um convite para usar a plataforma de Q&A que temos aqui, para outros propósitos, como por exemplo, ser um veículo de discursos, discussões sobre assuntos e ideias, pesquisas de opinião, brincadeiras com o trabalho ou para ser *help-desk*.

O [Stack Exchange mudou seu modelo](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) e mudou para melhor. O que ficou claro na mudança é que os sites da rede não devem tentar agregar todo tipo de usuário. Apenas aqueles que acham a plataforma e as regras impostas (sim, impostas) pela equipe do SE e as comunidades individuais são ideais para elas, devem participar. Muitas pessoas que não tem suas opiniões efetivadas como guias para a comunidade acabam dizendo que ali tem um bando de ditadores. Não dá para se preocupar com isso. Mesmo que a ditadura fosse verdadeira, ela só é ruim quando você é obrigado participar dela e não existem meios de buscar alternativas.

> Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions

O lema do SE não é apenas fazer uma internet melhor. É fazer isso com a ajuda de especialistas.

## Eu sou "inclusionista"

Não se enganem. Vejam quantas vezes participei de fechamento de perguntas. Apesar de algumas pessoas, sem ter noção do meu histórico, me acusarem de eu querer sair fechando tudo que vejo pela frente. Posso errar em qualquer ponto, mas não faço irresponsavelmente.

Eu já dei minha opinião sobre algumas perguntas que devem ser fechadas. A comunidade precisa decidir sobre essas perguntas para que eu me decida pelas outras. Eu preciso ter coerência. Eu posso aceitar algumas coisas que não gosto, mas para isto terei que aceitar outras que eu acho ruim, porém melhor do que as primeiras. Se vamos abrir a porta para perguntas que beneficiam bem poucas pessoas, que pra mim, são as piores perguntas depois das aberrações, teremos que abrir a porta para muita coisa. Já tratei desse assunto em outras respostas minhas recentes.

Concordo com o texto aqui colocado que precisamos trazer as regras já definidas em outros sites para deixar claro para todo mundo como agir. E acho que um pouco de imposição do SE até vai bem. Em certo ponto.

Eu começo ver alguns problemas que podem levar ao mesmo ponto onde o Programmers chegou um dia. O site se perdeu e nunca mais se recuperou. Foi de grande ajuda para, pelo menos, por ordem na casa, a presença do Jeff e do Joel dando informações com autoridade, até impondo algumas coisas que eram necessárias, sem as quais o site teria descarrilhado para a morte. Imposição não é de toda ruim.

Algumas pessoas parecem não entender que certos problemas são difíceis de resolver depois que eles tomam conta do site. O SO e o P.SE estão cheios de exemplos. A impossibilidade de resolvê-los chega até ser argumento do porquê deve-se deixar rolar.

## Liderança

Quem lidera paga um preço também. Não podemos temer que algumas pessoas reclamem das ações que são tomadas para o bem da comunidade. Devemos dar voz a todos, devemos ouvir o que todos têm a dizer, mas não podemos ceder a pressões individuais.

Não sei se é óbvio para todos, mas ser moderador, não é a melhor forma de ganhar popularidade. Se alguém achar que ser moderador é agradar a comunidade, não pode ser moderador. Que fique claro para quem tem a intenção de sê-lo.

Certamente quem não é moderador, acha que ser um, é só benefício. Na prática você acaba até ficando mais limitado, porque quando fizer alguma coisa, tem que fazer em nome de todos e isso é uma responsabilidade enorme que precisa ser bem dosada. Na prática o moderador é um "*exception handler*", ou seja, ele deve ser uma medida extrema. Primeiro tem que deixar a comunidade agir. O moderador entra quando a comunidade falha. O que o moderador pode fazer sempre, é influenciar.

```
If (community == fails) throw Moderation;
```

Porque falei em moderador? O único moderador é o Gabe. De direito sim, mas os usuários mais ativos são moderadores de fato, apesar de não ter todas as ferramentas que um moderador tem. A responsabilidade é essencialmente a mesma. Não gosto de falsa modéstia. E posso dizer que hoje temos no máximo 4 nomes que já agem como moderadores, em maior ou menor grau. Se mais alguém começar agir como tal, eu incluirei na lista.

Os mais ativos precisam influenciar o bom comportamento desde já. Mesmo que às vezes errem. E isso vai acontecer muito.

## Conclusão

Precisamos entender o que é nossa plataforma e o que é nossa comunidade.

O resto, concordo, precisa mais participação. Mesmo que o clima esquente.

Respondi com um discurso o que foi perguntado (?) como discurso. Nenhum problema. Acho que evoluímos de alguma forma.

Errei no tom? Talvez. Sugira e critique.

Comment: Ainda bem que todos concordam que "precisa mais participação, mesmo que o clima esquente", porque às vezes desconfio que estou sendo impertinente...

Comment: Certamente não. Participações civilizadas como as suas sempre são importantes.

Answer (score 12):

A pergunta cobre muitos aspectos para a construção de um site saudável, ao mesmo tempo que tenta angariar ideias para criar uma estratégia que venha a criar meios para se poder definir o site.

Contudo existem factores *básicos* sem os quais o site não sobrevive e que me parecem que uma vez resolvidos são meio caminho andado para o que esta pergunta tenta obter como resposta:

1. ### Participação no META

   **A participação no META** de forma mais ou menos activa por parte da maior percentagem dos utilizadores do site, ainda mais nesta fase inicial **é crucial** para se conseguir definir aquilo que será o comportamento aceitável no futuro.

   Motivar a vinda ao META do site é um problema que tenho visto debatido inúmeras vezes mas até ao momento sem sucesso.

   Não contando um a um, em termos de utilizadores temos no META 12 páginas deles, a 36 por página dá um número aproximado de 432 utilizadores.

   Seguindo a mesma formula para o site principal, temos 36 páginas a 36 por página chegamos a um valor aproximado de 1296.

   Em suma, podemos ver que por motivo A ou B cerca de 1/3 dos utilizadores até ao momento existentes no site já vieram ao META. Mas estão activamente a manifestar-se para a definição do site principal, expressando a sua opinião ou votando em concordância ou discordância com as opiniões expressadas?

   A resposta é claramente não! Apenas [25 utilizadores](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters) manifestaram a sua opinião através do voto.

   Isto diz-nos que menos de 2% dos utilizadores tem uma noção concreta de que a sua participação no META é crucial para o crescimento e definição do site.

   #### Sugestão

   Esta barra é chamativa o suficiente! Por que não utilizar a mesma para motivar os utilizadores a virem ao META e deixarem a sua opinião?

   [image: Captura de Tela]

   Quando já fizemos o *Tour* ela desaparece, o espaço dela podia estar a ser utilizado para promover o META, que apesar de ter o quadrado na coluna lateral direita, claramente não é suficiente.
2. ### A Ajuda

   Quando acedemos ao menu "Ajuda", na segunda opção podemos ler "[Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)", mas da forma que está neste momento não ajuda ninguém.

   É certo que algumas coisas devem ser definidas antes da *Ajuda* ser eficiente, nomeadamente o que deve ou não ser aceite no site a nível de perguntas e respostas, mas existe todo um outro universo na área de ajuda que não está *preso* por essas definições.

   Eu vejo que o site fui criado para atingir um determinado grupo de programadores ou relacionados com programação que não se dão bem com Inglês para estarem no SOEN, pelo que vem aqui para serem ajudados ou ajudarem, mas não são recebidos nem com uma ajuda básica ao funcionamento do site!?

   Ok, temos o Tour... e então? não me parece que esteja a ser prático o suficiente. Em qualquer outro site da SE se vejo um comportamento, pergunta ou resposta fora do contexto do site, deixo um comentário para a área de ajuda que cobre o assunto de forma detalhada. Como resultado, no maior número de vezes o utilizador responde passado um tempo a dizer "Ok, fui ler, já entendi, obrigado!". Aqui não podemos (*devemos*) ainda fazer isso...

   Vamos ver uma coisa, já vi utilizadores que nem sabem como aceitar uma resposta ou para que servem as setas ao lado das respostas e perguntas! Acho perfeitamente normal, a uns anos atrás, quando comecei a participar na SE eu também não sabia, mas fui à página de ajuda e fiquei a saber! É este tipo de coisas que já devia estar traduzido e acessível ao publico alvo deste site. Especialmente se este assunto está sumariado na *Tour*.

   #### Sugestão

   Se queremos um site saudável, a ajuda deveria estar traduzida e nos textos onde ainda precisamos definir como vai ser o comportamento do site, das duas uma:

   - Texto com linhas gerais desencorajando perguntas "amplas de mais" ou respostas "apenas link", entre outros que já são a *regra da casa*;
   - Mensagem a indicar que em caso de dúvida podem ser vir ao META e colocar uma pergunta a pedir ajuda antes de colocarem a pergunta no site.

   Ambas as opções, uma mistura das duas ou qualquer outra coisa certamente será mais proveitoso como ajuda do que uma página com tópicos em Inglês que sempre que se fala nela a resposta é "Isso vai ser alterado...".

---

## Sumário

Se queremos definir o site, se queremos responder à pergunta "Qual é este Stack Overflow?", temos que reverter os números em cima apresentados:

- Não é 2% dos utilizadores que vão definir o site, é 98%;
- Não é 1/3 dos utilizadores do site na meta, é 1/3 dos utilizadores do site fora da meta!

Depois de estar mais pessoal envolvido, vai ser fácil responder a muitas das perguntas chave que já foram colocadas na META para tentar estabelecer as "regras do jogo".

Comment: Acho que sua **sugestão** por si só dá uma ótima *feature-request*.

Answer (score 1):

Eu ia dar apenas a minha opinião em comentário mas achei por bem responder mesmo.

O que eu acho é que estamos muito ligados no SOEN.

**"Nós temos de fazer o nosso próprio SO."**

Como sabem há muito conteúdo em Inglês na *internet*, em Português há muito pouco. Acho que foi por isso mesmo que estamos a ter a oportunidade de fazer as nossas próprias regras, para podermos englobar o conteúdo que seja pertinente, para nós comunidade.

Acho que a ideia é mesmo essa com o "puramente subjetivo", deixar que sejamos nós, aos poucos, com o passar do tempo a decidir e a moldar consoante as necessidades forem surgindo. Acho que não falta nada para que a comunidade seja mais participativa, falta é deixar passar tempo, todos os dias entra gente nova, acho que estamos "*a por o carro a frente dos bois*".

Se fossemos agora a definir essas regras o que poderia acontecer é que num futuro próximo uma pergunta que estivesse *off-topic* passa-se a ser importante para a comunidade, para o 1 milhão de utilizadores novos.

**Eu acho que devemos ir fazendo as regras conforme as necessidades, até porque se forem definidas já, podem influênciar o que poderá ser o trilho percorrido pelo SOPT.**

Quanto aos 2% que se fala, amigos acaba por ser natural que isso assim aconteça uma vez que são cerca de 2% que utilizam o SOPT **regularmente**. Temos de deixar a comunidade evoluir mais **e ir vendo do que ela precisa**.

Por fim acho muito bem este tipo de questões, porque é nestas questões que ficamos a saber se precisamos ou não de estabelecer ou não certas regras.

Comment: Não sei se minha opinião ficou bem clara na minha pergunta, até porque ela foi postada em um outro momento, em que a participação era menor. Hoje eu colocaria da seguinte maneira: não temos ainda nenhuma regra formalizada em relação ao que é on-topic ou off-topic, nem em relação a certos tipos comuns de pergunta como pedidos de recomendação. Em relação ao que já apareceu no site até agora, e considerando como a comunidade reagiu, o que podemos considerar como um conjunto mínimo de diretrizes consensuais, que sirvam como lastro das decisão dos usuários atuais, e como orientação aos novos?

Comment: Fique claro que não quero sair definindo um monte de regras sem nenhum embasamento prático no nosso próprio site (ou seja, não quero importar as regras do SO). Mas precisamos levar em conta que nossa ferramenta funciona de determinada maneira. Por exemplo, existe o fechamento de perguntas. Então, como usar isso? Como temos usado isso? E considerando como temos usado, como achamos que deva ser usado? Acredito que sem diretrizes o site fique uma bagunça completa, com cada usuário agindo como bem entender, e isso não é bom. A central de ajuda já é um começo, do que mais precisamos?

Comment: Sendo assim como dizes, então poderia-se criar um tópico aqui para debater isso, para que toda a gente possa sugerir diretrizes para serem aprovadas por voto na resposta. @Gabe?

Comment: Apenas pra fazer um contraponto: se maioria fizesse bem sempre, os fóruns seriam uma beleza. A rede SE só funciona por ter definições claras ao se criar uma comunidade, e se respeitá-las. Isso aqui já está virando uma bagunça pq qualquer um chega do nada e muda as regras (justamente por não serem sólidas). A proposta original do SOpt na Área 51, ao meu ver, foi praticamente jogada no lixo. Pra mim a rede SE sempre foi referência por qualidade das respostas, e não apenas quantidade. O SOpt pra mim ja virou exceção. E sem regras, vai ficar cada vez mais "genérico". O que não é bom.

Comment: Jorge, não caberia isso tudo numa única meta-pergunta, mas já existem algumas e outras podem ser criadas para esse fim. O que acho que falta é a própria comunidade e a Stack Exchange (de maneira oficial) "baterem o martelo" de que neste momento X vale e Y não vale. Digo neste momento porque qualquer regra pode sempre ser rediscutida.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu estou de acordo que se possam discutir algumas regras. Embora ache que quanto a *on-topic* ou *off-topic* deveria ficar para mais tarde quando já tivéssemos mais informação relevante do que nós, comunidade, queremos que seja *on* ou *off*.

Comment: @Bacco o que queres dizer com <<E sem regras, vai ficar cada vez mais "genérico">>?

Comment: @JorgeB. igual ao resto do que já temos na internet, que não se pode confiar. Se não há nada que faça com que as pessoas levem a sério suas postagens e atitudes, e que direcione a forma de fazê-lo e restrinja seus assuntos com algum critério, você tem uma massa de informação que precisa ser filtrada e refiltrada, isso não é melhor do que sair abrindo um monte de fórum e tentando ver o que serve e não serve. O SOzão funciona por ter critérios. Aqui não é o SOzão (infelizmente, no meu ver), mas poderiamos aprender ao menos isso com "ele".

Comment: @Bacco Eu concordo que haja um critério, mas que não seja "cego". Poderá se restringir as perguntas a determinados assuntos, mas aparecer uma pergunta pertinente que mereça estar aberta. Só não gostava que essa pergunta fosse fechada só porque ser *off-topic* e ficar por responder. Não sei se me faço entender.

Comment: Vejam esta questão e a resposta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1344/7210

Comment: Curioso que me parece que o que é on-topic é o que costuma dar menos polêmica. Claro que ainda não sabemos as especifidades do que é é on e o que é off, mas sabemos em linhas gerais. O que é off, não nos interessa e deve ser fechado. Algo deve ser fechado **especialmente se** for off-topic. SE não não é SOpt, é EverythingPT.

Comment: @bigown Como eu disse ao Bacco eu concordo que haja critério, mas que não seja "cego".