# Devemos ter respostas gigantes no estilo Wikipédia/blog?

Tags: debate, respostas

Um dos motivos de fechamento de perguntas diz o seguinte (ênfase adicionada):

> ### Amplo demais
>
> Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas **seriam muito longas para este formato**. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que **possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos**.

De uma maneira geral, eu gosto de perguntas no estilo **"Quando é recomendado...?"** ou **"Por que devemos...?"**, acho que a maioria das minhas perguntas é nesse estilo.

Mas o Stack-PT tá cheio de respostas gigantes, quase um artigo completo, o que foge um pouco do objetivo inicial da rede (vide a citação acima).

Não criei essa pergunta para dar a minha opinião, mas para descobrir qual é a opinião da comunidade. Talvez as respostas deveriam ser um resumo e conter *links* para artigos de blog mais completos, no caso de assuntos muito amplos. Ou talvez seja interessante manter as respostas bem completas, tornando o Stack uma espécie de enciclopédia de programação. Não tenho minha opinião formada sobre isso ainda.

Answer (score 17):

### Sobre o comprimento das respostas

Não há nada errado com respostas longas, muito pelo contrário. Eu as vejo como excelentes conteúdos, e **conteúdo de qualidade é justamente o que o site deseja ter**. Isso, claro, partindo do pressuposto que estamos falando de respostas longas com conteúdo de qualidade, e não de ruído, ou trechos gigantescos de código.

O motivo de fechamento como "amplo demais" não define o que é uma resposta "muito longa"; mesmo a parte dos "poucos parágrafos" é sujeita a interpretação" – e foi traduzida do inglês *a few paragraphs*, que também pode ser lido como "alguns parágrafos" – ainda mais vago que "poucos".

O limite de tamanho, ao meu ver, está dado no que é imposto pela ferramenta (30.000 caracteres), e pelo que está dito na [Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (a ênfase é minha):

> Suas perguntas devem ter um escopo razoável. Se você pode imaginar **um livro inteiro** que responda à sua pergunta, está perguntando demais.

É bom também citar alguns pontos do artigo [*Subjetivo bom, subjetivo ruim*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective), quando define as principais características de "grandes questões sujetivas":

> **Grandes questões subjetivas inspiram respostas que explicam o "porquê" e o "como"**.
>
> **Grandes questões subjetivas tendem a ter respostas longas e não curtas.** (...) Compartilhar uma experiência leva pelo menos um parágrafo, idealmente vários parágrafos. (...) Compartilhe suas experiências detalhadas, para que todos possamos aprender com elas.
>
> **Grandes questões subjetivas insistem que opiniões devem ser apoiadas por fatos e referências. Opinião não é *de todo* ruim**, desde que ela seja apoiada por outra coisa que não "*porque eu sou um especialista*", ou "*porque eu disse isso*", ou "*porque sim*". (...) forneça evidências para apoiar suas alegações.

Esses três pontos, assim como outros trechos que não citei, não apenas defendem respostas longas, como as estimulam – já que explicar o "porquê" e o "como", compartilhar experiências e embasar o que é dito com referências são tarefas que exigem espaço.

### Sobre o formato das perguntas e respostas

É bom mencionar esta discussão aqui no meta foi postada logo após uma discussão nos comentários da pergunta *[Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21767/por-que-devemos-evitar-retornar-c%C3%B3digos-de-erro)*

Alguns comentários postados ali, eu outras postagens que já vi espalhadas pelo site, partem do princípio de que o site não é para isso, e sim apenas para resolver problemas pontuais de códigos específicos. Embora o site sirva sim para isso, focar demais nisso é, na minha opinião, um grande erro. Vejam o que está acontecendo no SO original: toneladas de perguntas tipo *help desk* por dia, poucas respostas que sirvam para alguém mais além de quem perguntou, e um grande número de especialistas insatisfeitos, reclamando diariamente da qualidade do conteúdo no meta. E não é porque perguntas subjetivas (boas) ou respostas longas sejam proibidas (não são), mas porque o volume de help desk é gigantesco lá. É isso que queremos aqui?

Vou dizer uma coisa aqui que talvez muitos discordem, mas **na minha opinião** uma boa resposta não é aquela que resolve o problema de quem perguntou, e sim a que mostra a essa pessoa não só como resolver esse problema, mas também outros similares que vier a encontrar no futuro. E mais, que seja eficiente em explicar isso não só para quem fez a pergunta, mas para qualquer um que esteja lendo. É o que alguns têm dito por aí, *ensinar a pescar em vez de entregar o peixe.* Ou seja, não basta um código consertado, é necessário explicar como funciona o conserto, e por que aquela determinada solução foi escolhida e não outras.

Também tem gente criticando a pergunta e resposta que mencionei acima porque seria mais "um artigo da Wikipedia" ou "postagem de blog". De fato não somos uma enciclopédia nem um blog, mas temos coisas em comum com esses formatos. Veja este diagrama, [divulgado por um dos criadores do SO ainda durante o beta do SO](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/help-us-beta-test/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nós somos o asterisco na intersecção dos quatro círculos. Não somos inteiramente nem a Wikipedia, nem um blog, nem um fórum, nem o Digg, nem o Reddit, mas temos pontos em comum com todos eles.

### Concluindo

Para além de toda a minha argumentação acima, é sempre bom relembrar o que foi dito no [primeiro post do nosso meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com):

> - Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?
> - Ela aumenta ou diminui o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?

Eu mesmo [já critiquei essas afirmações](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/522/aqui-%C3%89-um-stack-overflow-qual) por serem vagas, mas acho que para esta discussão eles são suficientes: bons conteúdos, seja lá qual for o seu comprimento, definitivamente tornam a internet um lugar melhor e aumentam o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site. Eu não consigo imaginar nenhum problema para o site ou para a comunidade que possa ser causado por uma (boa) resposta longa. A única pessoa que pode sair perdendo é quem escreveu tal conteúdo, já que provavelmente dedicou um tempo considerável a essa tarefa. Nós, enquanto leitores, só saímos ganhando!

Vou então parafrasear o Robert Cartaino em *Subjetivo bom, subjetivo ruim*: **vida longa às boas respostas gigantes!**

Comment: Nada como uma resposta gigante para responder a esta pergunta, hehe.

Comment: Por experiência própria posso dizer que não perdi tempo em nenhuma das minhas respostas longas. Eu aprendi **muito** durante o processo. E aprendo mesmo depois de postá-las. Por isso costumo melhorá-las depois. E gostaria que outras pessoas respondessem junto para eu aprender mais. Seria bom também para não ter apenas uma visão (aqui não é a Wikipedia que só pode ter uma visão teoricamente imparcial). Quem sabe até alguém escrever tudo o que eu escrevi em 1 ou 2 parágrafos.

Comment: @bigown Concordo com esta resposta e com a sua. Eu sou um profissional completamente diferente após responder a algumas perguntas com respostas longas. Todo trabalho é um processo de pesquisa. E isso envolve comparação com a abordagem de outros usuário. Já aprendi bastante com muitos usuários aqui.

Comment: O único ponto é que às vezes fica muito conteúdo para ler. Algo que venho tentando fazer é resumir algumas coisas, sem tentar criar uma "prova científica", além cortar palavras desnecessárias para não ser desnecessariamente prolixo. Embora ser prolixo seja uma característica de todos que gostam de informações bem definidas e detalhadas.

Comment: Não caberia editar o motivo de fechamento "Muito amplo", removendo a parte do "muito longo" e "poucos parágrafos"? Pois "amplo" aqui tem um sentido diferente.

Comment: Um parágrafo, dois parágrafos, três... não acredito que a explanação seja tão grande... ora, não é que é! Parabéns pelo meta-meta ;)

Comment: Eu também compartilho a sua opinião. :)

Answer (score 6):

Eu enxergo da seguinte forma: independentemente de pontuação (que, convenhamos, é algo praticamente apenas simbólico), quem escreve uma resposta longa de qualidade gasta um tempo precioso pra fazer isso, de modo que seguramente não o faz de forma leviana (isto é, apenas pra ter a melhor resposta, ou a mais votada, ou a mais "bonita", e sei lá mais o que). Eu diria que pessoas que fazem isso (e gosto de pensar que estou incluido nesse grupo) prezam pela qualidade da informação e para que ela esteja disponível para a comunidade.

De fato, respostas longas são complicadas (principalmente quando só têm texto) pois tendem a ser difíceis e pouco divertidas de ler. Para OPs com interesses pontuais, tais respostas se tornam ainda menos atrativas, porque quem perguntou está com pressa pra ter sua dúvida esclarecida e nem sempre está interessado em "aprender", apenas em "resolver". Em outros casos, em que o interesse é aprender, não vejo mesmo porque o tamanho da resposta seria um problema.

Agora, considerando que isto é uma COMUNIDADE complexa (como demonstra o Diagrama de Venn na resposta do @bfavaretto) e não meramente um fórum, na **minha opinião** nós devemos prezar para que o conteúdo tenha a maior utilidade possível, para o maior número de pessoas possível. De certa forma, o formato dos sites do grupo SE preza por isso, porque de fato permite que novas respostas continuem sendo oferecidas mesmo após uma ter sido aceita. Talvez você não tenha parado pra pensar sobre isso, mas qual seria o propósito desse tipo de comportamento senão permitir que novos conhecimentos sejam sempre agregados?

Assim, uma resposta longa bem formulada para uma pergunta objetiva apenas significa que alguém (um especialista, mais provavelmente, ou alguém que simplesmente gastou seu tempo estudando o assunto) teve tempo e disposição para já oferecer imediatamente conteúdo que talvez seria oferecido ao longo de um tempo maior por meio de mais respostas.

Pra concluir, acho que também as vezes nós levamos muito a sério o que está escrito nas regras. Essa indicação de "pense a respeito se as respostas seriam muito longas" colocada na ajuda para a **formulação de perguntas** me parece muito mais direcionada a evitar que as perguntas sejam superficiais e genéricas do que evitar que as respostas a elas sejam longas.

Comment: Concordo, e destaco o último parágrafo. As "regras" nem são tão claras, e mesmo no SO são sujeitas a interpretação. E realmente a observação sobre o tamanho das respostas é voltada a evitar perguntas problemáticas.

Answer (score 5):

A respeito disso tenho a opinião de permitir respostas com conteúdos grandes, isso claro quando for necessário.

Penso que, colocar apenas o link de algum site/blog pode ocorrer de alguém tentar acessar e o site está quebrado. O bacana mesmo é citar de onde pegou o conteúdo e colocar o texto dele.

Acho bacana perguntas mais completas pois dessa maneira o aprendizado dentro do site é grande.

Answer (score 3):

Eu particularmente detesto ter que ler respostas compridíssimas, até porque a grande maioria das dúvidas que tenho são coisas pontuais, então objetividade é essencial.

Também como minha opinião, a comunidade aparentemente é conivente com prolixidade e debates filosóficos, com respostas aceitas que não apontam uma solução pro problema perguntado: apenas divagam e divagam sobre dúzias de aspectos de programação, código, padrões e outras coisas envolvidas. Lembra mais o padrão do [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) misturado com o [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Eu não procuraria o Stack Overflow pra aprender um Framework ou um padrão de projeto (pra "aprender a pescar"). Há outros sites com este propósito, como o CodeProject, blogs especializados e o GitHub.

O que sinto é que respostas **muito boas** de 2, 3 linhas são simplesmente desvalorizadas, e que respondem **super bem** ao que foi perguntado. O SO gringo é um exemplo clássico disso. Lá as respostas mais votadas não são as enormes, as capitulares ou as filosóficas: são as que resolvem o problema da melhor e mais rápida maneira possível.

E é assim que procuro responder: respostas sucintas, que não exijam muito tempo pra ler e ricas em código, que é isso que interessa pras pessoas que buscam algo aqui. Tenho respostas compridas também, mas elas tentam ser enxutas ao máximo, com o que realmente é importante. Essas questões mais "metafísicas" eu nem procuro responder.

Mas, como falei ali pra cima, isto é opinião, e possivelmente muita gente não concorda.

**Adendo:** Não precisam me lembrar que aqui não é o SO gringo. Já cansei de ler esse argumento.

Comment: Nós temos os dois tipos de usuários aqui: os que preferem perguntas mais diretas e específicas e os que preferem as "filosóficas." Eu particularmente acho que há espaço para os dois (e ainda outros) tipos de perguntas aqui. Por que limitar demais o escopo? No SO-EN isso faz mais sentido pois há outros sites de programação, mas aqui não. Há ainda algumas regras para tentar garantir a qualidade, é claro. Mas no mais, o site é de todos.

Comment: Você tocou num ponto importante que está nas entrelinhas de toda esta discussão: os votos. Algumas respostas (e perguntas) acumulam votos mais rapidamente que outras, mas com o tempo conteúdos de qualidade (independente do tamanho) tendem a ser valorizados. No SO gringo acontece isso, e aqui espero que aconteça também. Mesmo assim, sempre haverá respostas injustiçadas. O que podemos fazer com elas é editá-las, melhorá-las e chamar a atenção das pessoas para elas.

Comment: @Andrey Não é uma crítica. É uma observação, embora não seja algo que eu goste. O ideal seria ter um Programmers em Português.

Comment: @bfavaretto Nem é tanto por isso, mas já virou um clichê que resposta boa é resposta comprida.

Comment: @bfavaretto *"chamar a atenção das pessoas para elas"*. Isso é importante. No SO-EN vemos muitos comentários de resposta como *"essa é a melhor resposta porque..."* ou *"esta resposta não é adequada porque..."*

Comment: Entendo e acho as suas colocações bastante justas. Talvez o ponto principal dessa discussão deva ser o que cada um entende como sendo os objetivos ideais do SOPT, principalmente na dimensão CONHECIMENTO <-> RESOLUÇÃO. Se os rumos tiverem de ser apenas no sentido de resolução pontual de problemas, respostas longas deixam mesmo de ser interessantes. Particularmente eu concordo com o primeiro comentário do @Andrey, e acho que por ser praticamente uma plataforma única em português faz mesmo sentido termos um escopo mais flexível.

Comment: @LuizVieira Concordo, mas ainda assim isso não torna uma resposta curta pobre em conhecimento. Há respostas que ensinam muito com poucas palavras, sem divagação, sem prolixidade.

Comment: É verdade, e eu creio que ninguém chegou a tentar argumentar contra existirem respostas curtas de qualidade. Mas, convenhamos: dizer que uma resposta é ruim só por ser curta me parece tão dogmático quanto dizer que ela é prolixa só por ser longa. A transferência de conhecimento explícito em texto não é sempre tão objetiva quanto a criação de um exemplo mínimo executável de código, por exemplo.

Comment: Concordo. Respostas longas pra coisas simples são até chatas.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que `Amplo demais`, não deva ser limitado pelo tamanho da reposta em quantidade de caracteres, mas quando um assunto por sua complexidade e por poder ser abordado de tantas formas distintas se torna amplo demais para ser discutido como uma simples questão, tornando se necessário direcionar o foco para algo mais especifico ou fragmentar o todo em diversas outras questões. O comprimento da respostas (quando não está grande para encher linguiça) é válido e muito bem vindo, pois torna mais rica a resposta. Existem respostas curtas e boas pois são objetivas. Os próprios exemplos de código dependendo da questão já deixaria a resposta longa, mas podem ser vitais para o entendimento do projeto.

Comment: Reposta boa é a que soluciona a dúvida, sem causar causar duvidas novas.