# Perguntas curtas são necessariamente inadequadas?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Não achei [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28090/como-posso-renderizar-s%C3%B3-a-tabela-dentro-da-minha-p%C3%A1gina) tão obscura assim. Ela é curta, mas me pareceu objetiva o bastante para não ser colocada em suspenso.

No caso, o usuário quer uma explicação geral sobre o assunto: "como renderizar apenas uma tabela com jquery", ponto. Isso não me parece diferente de outras perguntas onde o que se pretende é conhecer um procedimento geral.

Então eu pergunto: qual foi o critério usado para `justificar o motivo apresentado para` a suspensão? Perguntas curtas, mesmo que objetivas, são inadequadas?

**Edição**

Embora minha dúvida seja realmente mais ampla, e por isso considero válidos os comentários e respostas recebidos até o momento, acho justo tentar explicar o que motivou meu questionamento, tendo como referência a pergunta citada acima.

A justificativa da suspensão foi o fato dela não ser clara. Só que ela é clara. A resposta é que tem potencial para ser ampla, por se tratar de uma dúvida sobre um procedimento.

Portanto, a pergunta não me pareceu "vaga" ou pouco clara, e sim genérica. Mas perguntas genéricas são aceitas, bem como perguntas que poderiam ser resolvidas com pesquisas são aceitas.

O que sobra então? O fato de ser curta? Uma falha de construção de frase ("a tabela" e "uma tabela", faz muita diferença) que poderia ter sido resolvida com boa vontade de interpretação e/ou um comentário de orientação, dando um tempo para o autor se corrigir antes de aplicar um bloqueio? A pergunta foi feita há 14h (no momento em que escrevo esta edição), e há sete já estava suspensa.

Entendam apenas, por favor, que não estou questionando a justiça da suspensão, embora pareça. O que estou fazendo é analisar um caso atual, na minha opinião, bastante confuso, para definir a melhor conduta quando for a minha vez de decidir o que fazer.

Comment: O critério utilizado pode ser encontrado logo abaixo da pergunta na caixa cinza: "put on hold as não é claro o que você está perguntando". Eu não vou dar minha opinião se o que ele está perguntando é claro ou não pois não sou muito bom em JQuery, mas esse foi o motivo de fechamento escolhido pelos usuários listados logo na sequencia da frase.

Comment: @Math, editei a pergunta para tentar ser mais claro.

Comment: Entendi. Vamos aguardar as respostas então :)

Comment: Eu fui um dos que votei para fechar porque não percebi o que o AP quer. @Blau explicas-me o que ele quer?

Comment: @JorgeB. Como disse aqui na minha pergunta, ele quer saber como renderizar apenas uma tabela com jquery. Se isso é possível, se isso implica em um erro conceitual, se é ou não possível, caberia a quem tem conhecimento e disposição esclarecer numa resposta ou num comentário, penso eu. Aliás, ontem mesmo eu respondi uma pergunta que trazia um erro conceitual (classe e pseudoclasses no CSS), esclarecendo o AP e oferecendo informações úteis para futuras buscas.

Comment: Eu não percebi muito bem o que ele quer. Se fosse "posso renderizar utilizando ajax" ou "como faço para renderizar uma tabela em ajax" Na altura li e fiquei sem perceber o que ele queria. Então pus para fechar. Qualquer coisa a comunidade abre. Não vi ninguém até agora a votar para reabrir. Porque será? Talvez mais gente como eu não percebeu o que o AP queria. Não votei por fechar por ser pequena, e sim por não perceber o que o AP queria.

Comment: Não te precisas explicar é muito bom qd tens duvidas abrires a discussão aqui :)

Comment: E como a gente vota para reabrir, é só votar na pergunta? Eu sou palpiteiro, mas só estou aqui há uma semana, por isso essa e muitas outras dúvidas vão surgindo. :D

Comment: Tem um link para votar para reabrir, mas só aparece para quem tem pelo menos 500 pontos de reputação. E fique sempre à vontade para trazer discussões como esta aqui para o meta, é o lugar certo para isso sim. Sobre a pergunta, vou responder abaixo.

Comment: Não entendo muito de javascript, mas neste caso em específico, concordo que a pergunta poderia ser mais clara, pois reparei que ele deu mais explicações sobre o problema dele nos comentários do que na pergunta em si... Pessoalmente, odeio quando as pessoas fazem isso, pois além de forçar aos próximos a lerem os comentários para entender o problema dele (o que a pergunta deveria fazer), a tendência é ficar cada vez pior de entender a pergunta, pois outros comentários podem ofuscar esta explicação... Talvez se ele editasse a pergunta, ao invés de comentar seu problema, ela nem fosse fechada...

Answer (score 11):

O comprimento da pergunta ([ou resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1563/74)) não diz nada sobre sua qualidade. Mas nesse caso eu não consigo mesmo entender a pergunta.

Talvez ela seja mesmo sobre como fazer *append* de um elemento usando jQuery, mas também pode não ser isso. Não dá para entender o contexto. Quando ele diz "**só** a tabela" (ênfase minha), o que será o resto? E quando menciona ajax, por que será? Será que a tabela vem de outra requisição? Será que já está no DOM?

Não vejo como reabrir a pergunta sem antes esclarecer essas questões.

Comment: Estava a editar a minha resposta para cobrir esta pergunta específica, mas acredito que sua resposta já cobriu todos os pontos necessários.

Comment: O ajax foi citado no seguinte contexto: "Como posso fazer, utilizar o jquery ajax?" (uma pergunta) Ele escreve mal, mas dá para entender perfeitamente isso. Sobre "renderizar", em muitas linguagens isso significa simplificadamente alterar/montar e exibir algo dinamicamente, e imagino que não seja diferente com jquery. Ou seja, tendo a exibição completa de uma página, como fazer para produzir uma alteração ou exibição dinâmica em apenas um dos seus elementos, no caso, uma tabela, sem afetar os demais componentes. Tudo isso vem à minha mente, mas eu não sou especialista no assunto.

Comment: @Blau, eu não sei se ele quer montar a tabela por js ou só adicioná-la ao DOM. Nem se ele quer alterar uma tabela que já está na página. Seu comentário me faz achar ainda mais que a pergunta não é clara. Não vejo como responder sem inferir um montão de incógnitas.

Comment: @bfavaretto, ele também não sabe. Mesmo assim, onde fica o limite entre onde basta um comentário orientando e uma ação que, embora seja natural após algum tempo de SO, pode constranger um recém-chegado, como uma suspensão da pergunta? Além disso, (eu não sei mesmo) com a restrição vai alguma orientação além do link para a central de ajuda? Obrigado pela paciência.

Comment: Eu tenho certeza de que ele sabe mais do que a gente sobre o que ele quer fazer, @Blau. O procedimento ideal nesses casos é sempre pedir mais informações nos comentários (fiz isso agora). Quanto a votar para fechar, as opiniões são divididas: tem gente que prefere votar imediatamente (para evitar respostas que fiquem sem sentido quando a pergunta for esclarecida), e gente que prefere dar um tempo para a pessoa editar a pergunta, antes de decidir ou não pelo voto de fechamento. Eu sou a favor de sempre esperar um pouco, mas é difícil quantificar o tempo ideal.

Answer (score 6):

Minha interpretação é que essa pergunta sofre de dois motivos para fechamento *Ampla demais* e *Não é claro o que você está perguntando*.

> **Como posso renderizar só a tabela dentro da minha página? [em suspenso]**
>
> Como posso renderizar só a tabela dentro de uma página com jquery, utilizar o jquery ajax?

Particulamente, acho de muita baixa qualidade praticamente duplicar o título no corpo da pergunta. Aposto que pode ser possível fazer algo de boa qualidade desse jeito, mas como norma geral vejo pouca dedicação da pessoa em resolver seu próprio problema, vide [*Rubber Duck Problem Solving*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).

Especificamente, não entendo:

- que tabela é essa?
- que página é essa?
- qual jQuery já tentou?
- porque menciona AJAX?

Você diz que

> Portanto, a pergunta não me pareceu "vaga" ou pouco clara, e sim genérica.

Eu entendo *genérica* como "ampla" se inúmeras respostas são possíveis. A missão do site é dar [**respostas para perguntas práticas e detalhadas**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour):

[image: screenshot do Tour do site]

Você também diz que a pergunta

> poderia ter sido resolvida com boa vontade de interpretação e/ou um comentário de orientação, dando um tempo para o autor se corrigir antes de aplicar um bloqueio

- "boa vontade de interpretação" dá margem a respostas erradas, nada pior que escutar *"ah não, desculpa, isso eu já tentei"* depois de gastar tempo escrevendo uma resposta.
- colocar a pergunta em suspenso não é o fim do mundo, é só editá-la com novas informações e ela vai pra fila de análise, onde rapidamente vai ser votada para reabertura (ou não). Quem não conhece as regras da rede de sites Stack Exchange pode interpretar isso como algo indignante e injusto, mas são essas regras que fazem possível manter a alta qualidade do conteúdo e reduzir o ruído ao mínimo possível (p.ex., respostas erradas a perguntas mal feitas).

Comment: +1 exatamente a minha opinião.

Answer (score 2):

Não necessariamente, mas da mesma forma que ela possa ter parecido pouco clara, ela também poderia ser fechada por outros motivos como pode ser visto na página [Como Perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) consta:

> Procure e pesquise
>
> **Você procurou exaustivamente por uma resposta antes de formular a
>   pergunta?** Compartilhar sua pesquisa ajuda a todos. Diga-nos o que foi
>   que você encontrou e por que não satisfez às suas necessidades. Isto
>   demonstra que você usou seu tempo para tentar ajudar a si mesmo e nos
>   poupa de reiterar respostas óbvias e, principalmente, ajuda você a
>   obter uma resposta mais específica e relevante!

(ênfase minha)

E também:

Vale ver [esse comentário](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251673/what-shall-one-do-with-questions-which-are-obviously-closed-for-the-wrong-reason#comment4164_251673) do meta do SOEN no qual o moderador diz que se a pergunta está fechada mesmo que por motivos incorretos ela deve permanescer fechada até que os problemas existentes na mesma sejam corrigidos.

Outro problema com questões pequenas é que elas geralmente não atendem a esse item abaixo. (também extraído da página [Como Perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

> Seja específico
>
> Se você fizer uma pergunta vaga, terá uma resposta vaga. Porém, se
>   você der detalhes e contexto, podemos fornecer uma resposta útil.

Comment: Compreendo, mas vejo um problema de interpretação do sentido do termo "vago", que parece estar sendo utilizado incorretamente como um sinônimo de "genérico". O usuário do exemplo foi bastante específico, porque toda a pergunta dele visa objetivamente (e não vagamente) obter um procedimento: "como renderizar só a tabela com jquery". Quanto à pesquisa anterior, me parece que as decisões também correm o risco de ser arbitrárias, afinal temos duas perguntas em destaque, por exemplo, e ambas poderiam ser resolvidas com pesquisas, e não estão suspensas. Portanto, a dúvida permanece.

Comment: @Blau o que escrevi sobre ser específico não foi direcionado a questão mencionada e sim sobre um problema que *geralmente ocorre com questões pequenas* devido a sua pergunta-título ser um pouco mais ampla.

Comment: Perfeito, eu entendi e agradeço as informações.

Comment: Kyllopardiun talvez fosse mais interessante se sua resposta fosse direcionada, até mesmo pq o autor perguntou: "qual foi o critério usado para justificar o motivo apresentado para a suspensão?" em outras palavras, "pq a pergunta não é clara?". @Blau e para vc eu diria que seria interessante você adicionar a tag `pergunta-específica` na sua pergunta, para condizer com o texto dela e ficar mais claro o que você espera como resposta.

Comment: @Math eu fiquei em dúvida por estar somente na tag debate e por isso achei que deveria ser um tanto genérico.

Comment: @Math, isso mesmo. E eu acho que também vou incluir de uma forma mais clara o motivo da dúvida, que é, em suma: se a pergunta não é "vaga", se perguntas genéricas são aceitas, se perguntas que poderiam ser resolvidas com pesquisa são aceitas, o único pecado que parece sobrar é ela ser curta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendo o que o blau quer dizer. Realmente aqui na comunidade tem algumas pessoas que tem tendência a sinalizar perguntas como "amplas demais" quando muitas vezes a pessoa que faz a pergunta não faz idéia de que caminho seguir e vem para o stack encontrar um caminho, um ponto de partida, uma orientação e não uma "sinalização de pergunta imprópria".

Eu passei por isso aqui no stack, uma das minhas primeiras perguntas foi, em menos de um minuto, marcada como muito ampla. Felizmente, antes de ser suspenso, um usuário entendeu meu problema e me respondeu e hoje minha pergunta ajuda a muitas pessoas no stack.

([A pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link))

Quando a comunidade começa a reprimir perguntas fáceis ou simples, está reprimindo o desenvolvimento de novos usuários que muitas vezes não tem perguntas tão complexas assim mas que, naquele momento, precisam de ajuda.

Comment: A pergunta que você mencionou é um caso diferente. Ela é mesmo genérica (chegou a ser suspensa como "ampla demais"). O caso discutido aqui é de uma pergunta bem mais específica, porém com muitos detalhes faltando (que o autor certamente poderia esclarecer).

Answer (score -1):

Não. Idem as respostas.

Comment: É, não dá pra dizer que te falta objetividade :)