# Uma pergunta de tamanho curto pode ser considerada de baixa qualidade?

Tags: debate, perguntas, sinalização

Tenho algumas dúvidas a respeito de uma mensagem referente as perguntas que aparece na fila de analise de ***Publicações de baixa qualidade***, neste caso é esta mensagem, ela aparece como sinalização:

> Esta pergunta foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade devido ao tamanho
>   e conteúdo.

Na maioria dos casos um conteúdo de baixa qualidade é o responsável por votos contras ou votos de fechamento e isso faz sentido. Todavia, o *tamanho* da pergunta pode ser responsável por votos contras, sinalizações ou fechamentos ou fazer com que uma pergunta deste tipo seja de baixa qualidade?

Quando se remete ao *tamanho* da pergunta, diz-se que a pergunta é muito extensa ou é muito curta?

Vamos considerar uma pergunta de tamanho curto. Eu gostaria de saber que tipo de pergunta curta pode não estar em conformidade com as regras definidas na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) ou quais critérios a pergunta curta deve possuir para ser aceita pela comunidade? Uma vez que, existe [perguntas curtas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/27190) que são bem aceitas pela comunidade.

**Obs:**

*Existe esta [pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1805/perguntas-curtas-s%C3%A3o-necessariamente-inadequadas) relacionada ao assunto citado na minha pergunta, entretanto, ela é direcionada exclusivamente a uma pergunta especifica, e na minha pergunta eu me direciono ao assunto de uma forma mais geral.*

Comment: Creio que isso seja um "fator" base. Tais perguntas serão levadas para a fila de análise, onde será votada. Para ser realmente fechada, precisa de 5 votos ou um gold badge/moderador. Diante disso, receber uma notificação não me parece "sério". Se ela for ruim, será fechada, se não, será votada para deixar aberto, independente da quantidade de caracteres.

Answer (score 3):

Não importa o tamanho da pergunta, mas sim se ela traz contexto suficiente para que uma resposta útil pode ser dada.

Se as perguntas não foram bem-aceitas, é sinal de que não tinham contexto para incentivar respostas que fossem adequadas e úteis.

Comment: Sim o contexto pode ser crucial para decidir se uma pergunta é ou não de baixa qualidade.